# Swift Pushwood 'PushNotificationManager.h' file not found

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

This doesn't work.

> Failed to import bridging header '/Users/sitatel/xcodeProyects/Centros Virtuales/Centros Virtuales/Centros VirtualesUITests-Bridging-Header.h'

I followed this tutorial: http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/swift

The bridge header is OK, but `#import <PushNotificationManager.h>` does not work. How can I get this to work?

[image]

Comment: Try changing the brackets `< >` to quotation marks `" "` on line 6.

Comment: Thanks.. though they are use `code` " " `code` throws the same error